# Bipartite Matching of Array

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have arrays A and B. I have to find a maximum matching for array B, such that every index of B[i] can match with any index of A[j] if and only if **A[j]!=B[i] and A[j] is not previously matched**. For example:

```
A = {1 2 3 4}
B = {2 2 3 4}
Maximum Matching is 4 A[0]=B[3] , A[1]=B[2] , A[2]=B[1], A[3]=B[0]

A = {1 1 2}
B  = {1 1 2}
Maximum Matching 2 A[0]=B[2] , B[1]=No Matching , A[2]=B[0]
```

I know this is a maximum bipartite problem but problem is length of **A=B<=10^3 and A[i],B[i]<10^6**. Which will time-out my bipartite solution. Is there any better solution?

Code:

```
public static boolean is_match(int curr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {

        if(A[i] != curr && !V[i]) {

            V[i] = true;
            if(P[i] < 0 || is_match(P[i])) {
                P[i] = curr;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I call this function for every B:

```
for(int i:B){
    V = new boolean[n]
    if(is_match(i)) match++;
}
```

How can I improve my solution?

Comment: What bipartite algo you are implementing? Hungarian algo or max-flow version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be visualize as a max flow problem.

So, as the condition is `A[j]!=B[i] and A[j] is not previously matched`, so knowing whether index `i` from `A` matched to `j` or `k` in `B` with `B[j] == B[k]` is not important.

So, instead of represent the graph as a bipartite of `2*n` nodes, each node represent an index in array A and B, we can represent the problem as a flow graph with one source node, one sink node and list of nodes which represent unique values of A and B, and the capacity of node `a` (which represents `a` value in A) to source node is the  amount of indexes in `A` that has value `a`. Similarly, the capacity of node `b` mapped to the sinking node will be equaled the number of index in B has value `b`. Capacity between valid nodes from A to B are infinity.

For example, with array `A = {1, 1, 2, 2}` and `B = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3}`

So, we create a flow graph with a source and a sink node.

- Additionally, for array A, we create two additional nodes, one for value 1 and one for value 2. Source node will connect to these two nodes.
- For node B, we create three nodes, one for value 1, one for value 2, one for value 3.
- Now, source node will connect only to node from array A, with capacity equal : 2 for node represents value 1 (as there are two 1 in array A) and 2 for node represents value 2 (there are two 2 in array A).
- Sink node will connect only to node from array B, with capacity:
  1 for node represents value 1 (there is only one 1 in array B); 2 for node represents value 2 (there are two 2 in array B) and 4 for node represents value 3 (there are four 3 in array B).
- Connection between valid nodes from array A to B will have infinity capacity.

Now the rest of the job is to run a typical max flow algorithm.

Comment: i know how to implement max-flow algorithm , but i could not understand how i convert them to max-flow... i could not understand the last two lines of your answer

Comment: @user5349222 example added.

Comment: for the last step `Connection between array A and B will have infinity capacity. ` How it will ensure that it does not match the edge where A[i]=B[j]

Comment: Can i also track back which A[i] is matched with which B[j]... i guess backtracking will do it....

Comment: @user5349222 sorry, the connection is only between valid nodes, it is a bit vague.

Comment: @user5349222 backtracking is not necessary, for example, we can know 3 nodes with value 1 mapped to 3 nodes with value 2. So, just find 3 random unmatched nodes from A with value 1 and 3 unmatched nodes from B with value 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114538/discussion-between-user5349222-and-pham-trung).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can adapt your original algorithm to become O(n^2).

For each node in A: (i.e. this loop will repeat n times)

1. First scan to see if we can match this node with one in B. O(n)
2. If not, then we know that all unmatched nodes in B have the same value as our A node.  Call this value `a`.  Scan through all previous matchings to see if any A node (`!=a`) has been matched to a B node (`!=a`).  If so, change the mapping for this previous node and we have made a space for our new node.  O(n)

This is overall O(n^2).

The second pass will only fail to find a match when all the nodes in B not equal to `a` have already been mapped to nodes in A equal to `a`.  This means that there are too many nodes equal to `a` for a solution to be possible and the problem is impossible to every satisfy.

Comment: Yours solution is also very simple and quite fast...thanks

Answer (score 0):

The bipartite matching problem can be solved via the so-called [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) or can be modelled as a [maximum flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem); perhaps an implementation of these algorithms is faster.

The modelling as a flow problem works as follows; the items of `A` constutitue the left partition, the items of `B` consititute the right partition. Between the partitions, create an edge of capacity `1` between nodes if and only if it it possible to match them. Put a source node to the far left, connecting it to every node of the left partition with an edge of capacity `1`; also put a terminal node to the far right, connecting it to every node of the right partition with an edge of capacity `1`. If the flow from the source to the terminal is maximized, it will correspond to a maximum matching via selection of these edges in the middle which have a nonzero flow value.

Comment: can you explain how it can be modelled as maximum flow problem.